# trouble getting Date field on X axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
head(bktst.plotdata)   
   date      method  product type  actuals  forecast   residual   Percent_error month
1 2012-12-31  bauwd   CUSTM  NET  194727.51  -8192.00 -202919.51       -104.21 Dec12
2 2013-01-31  bauwd   CUSTM  NET  470416.27   1272.01 -469144.26        -99.73 Jan13
3 2013-02-28  bauwd   CUSTM  NET  190943.57  -1892.45 -192836.02       -100.99 Feb13
4 2013-03-31  bauwd   CUSTM  NET  -42908.91   2560.05   45468.96       -105.97 Mar13
5 2013-04-30  bauwd   CUSTM  NET -102401.68 358807.48  461209.16       -450.39 Apr13
6 2013-05-31  bauwd   CUSTM  NET -134869.73 337325.33  472195.06       -350.11 May13
```

I have been trying to plot my back test result using `ggplot2`. Given above a sample dataset. I have dates ranging from Dec2012 to Jul2013. 3 levels in 'method', 5 levels in 'product' and 2 levels in 'type'
I tried this code, trouble is that R is not reading x-axis correct, on the X-axis I am getting 'Jan, feb, mar, apr, may,jun, jul, aug', instead I expect R to plot Dec-to-Jul

```
month.plot1 <- ggplot(data=bktst.plotdata, aes(x= date, y=Percent_error, colour=method))
facet4 <- facet_grid(product~type,scales="free_y")
title3 <- ggtitle("Percent Error - Month-over-Month")
xaxis2 <- xlab("Date")
yaxis3 <- ylab("Error (%)")
month.plot1+geom_line(stat="identity", size=1, position="identity")+facet4+title3+xaxis2+yaxis3

# Tried changing the code to this still not getting the X-axis right
month.plot1 <- ggplot(data=bktst.plotdata, aes(x= format(date,'%b%y'), y=Percent_error, colour=method))
month.plot1+geom_line(stat="identity", size=1, position="identity")+facet4+title3+xaxis2+yaxis3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like you are plotting the last day of each month, so it actually makes sense to me that December 31 is plotted very very close to January.  If you look at the plotted points (with geom_point) you can see that each point is just to the left of the closest month axis.

It sounds like you want to plot years and months instead of actual dates.  There are a variety of ways you might do this, but one thing you could is to change the *day* part of the date to the first of the month instead of the last of the month.  Here I show how you could do this using some functions from package `lubridate` along with `paste` (I have assumed your variable `date` is already a `Date` object).

```
require(lubridate)
bktst.plotdata$date2 = as.Date(with(bktst.plotdata, 
                                    paste(year(date), month(date), "01", sep = "-")))
```

Then the plot axes start at December.  You can change the format of the x axis if you load the `scales` package.

```
require(scales)
ggplot(data=bktst.plotdata, aes(x = date2, y=Percent_error, colour=method)) +
    facet_grid(product~type,scales="free_y") +
    ggtitle("Percent Error - Month-over-Month") +
    xlab("Date") + ylab("Error (%)") +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_date(labels=date_format(format = "%m-%Y"))
```

Comment: smith,   thanks you sir, it worked. However, ideally it should not label Jan2013 instead of Dec2012. Dont know if a user supposed to know that if you are ploting last day of the month, label will effectively switch to one month ahead of time. In my case it doesnt matter if I plot first or last day of month, but in some cases data collection was done on exactly 31st Dec 2012. Anyways thanks much for the solution you gave me, good to see someone from Corvallis, I went to school in OSU

Comment: @anand I was trying to make the point that you plotted your points at the day level.  If you plot a value for December 31st,2012 that value will be right *next* to the axis for January 2013.  So you were asking ggplot to map a value to December 31, 2012 when you really wanted to map a value to December 2012.  This answer was one way to do that by plotting everything to the 1st of each month.  You could have reformatted your dates to just years-months with `format`, as well, but then you'd have had characters instead of dates.